# How do I select MAX/MIN from multiple tables, along with other columns from MIN/MAX row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query where I JOIN 4 weekly "summary" tables, and SELECT a MIN and a MAX of units FROM each table. This would give me the highest/lowest total units sold for, and I'm pulling an average from another table.

```
    SELECT
            L4.TotalUnits / 4   AS AvgMvmt,
            MIN(Ago.TotalUnits) AS LowMvmt,
            MAX(Ago.TotalUnits) AS HighMvmt
    FROM

            RTG_LOOKUP_LAST4 AS L4 INNER JOIN
            (
                    SELECT  UCC12UPCCode, TotalUnits, Date
                    FROM    [CACTUS].[dbo].[RTG_Lookup2_Last1]

                    UNION

                    SELECT  UCC12UPCCode, TotalUnits, Date
                    FROM    [CACTUS].[dbo].[RTG_Lookup2_2_Ago]

                    UNION

                    SELECT  UCC12UPCCode, TotalUnits, Date
                    FROM    [CACTUS].[dbo].[RTG_Lookup2_3_Ago]

                    UNION

                    SELECT  UCC12UPCCode, TotalUnits, Date
                    FROM    [CACTUS].[dbo].[RTG_Lookup2_4_Ago]
            ) AS Ago
                    ON Ago.UCC12UPCCode = L4.UCC12UPCCode
    WHERE
            L4.UCC12UPCCode = '01254601144'
    GROUP BY
            L4.TotalUnits
```

Now I need to add two more columns, `HighDate` and `LowDate`. These columns represent the date for the week that sold the highest/lowest units.

The `Ago` table looks like this:

```
UCC12UPCCode  TotalUnits  Date
------------- ----------- ----------
01254601144   90          2018-04-14
01254601144   98          2018-05-05
01254601144   107         2018-04-21
01254601144   132         2018-04-28
```

How would pull the `Date` column from the correct table so my end results looks like below:

```
LowMvmt     HighMvmt    LowDate    HighDate
----------- ----------- ---------- ----------
90          132         2018-04-14 2018-04-28
```

E: Fiddle 
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=749c59e1f11bc2146a605072f1ef7d98

Comment: I mean, just use `MIN(Date)` and `MAX(Date)`?. (you also need to stop grouping by the `TotalUnits`)

Comment: `MIN/MAX(Date)` will return just that, min/max date, not the date that corresponds to `MIN(Ago.TotalUnits)` (if the first 2 total units, `90` and `98` were swapped, `MIN(date)` will not be correct.). I also have to group by unless i remove `L4.TotalUnits / 4   AS AvgMvmt`, which i need

Comment: You could try providing an [SQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) with sample data and your desired result - your question is quite complex -- help us to help you! :-)

Comment: @Vérace see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a another option

```
WITH Ago AS (
    SELECT  UCC12UPCCode, TotalUnits, Date
    FROM    [CACTUS].[dbo].[RTG_Lookup2_Last1]

    UNION

    SELECT  UCC12UPCCode, TotalUnits, Date
    FROM    [CACTUS].[dbo].[RTG_Lookup2_2_Ago]

    UNION

    SELECT  UCC12UPCCode, TotalUnits, Date
    FROM    [CACTUS].[dbo].[RTG_Lookup2_3_Ago]

    UNION

    SELECT  UCC12UPCCode, TotalUnits, Date
    FROM    [CACTUS].[dbo].[RTG_Lookup2_4_Ago]
    ),
    Ranked AS (
    SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UPC ORDER BY TotalUnits, Date) LowUnitRank, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UPC ORDER BY TotalUnits DESC, Date) HighUnitRank
    FROM Ago
    )
SELECT L4.UCC12UPCCode,
    MAX(CASE WHEN LowUnitRank = 1 THEN TotalUnits END) LowTotalUnits,
    MAX(CASE WHEN HighUnitRank = 1 THEN TotalUnits END) HighTotalUnits,
    MAX(CASE WHEN LowUnitRank = 1 THEN Date END) LowUnitDate,
    MAX(CASE WHEN HighUnitRank = 1 THEN Date END) HighUnitDate
FROM RTG_LOOKUP_LAST4 L4
    INNER JOIN Ranked r ON L4.UCC12UPCCode = r.UCC12UPCCode
GROUP BY L4.UCC12UPCCode;
```

I've done this using a CTE query as I find it easier to follow and explain.

The first CTE is just your `Ago` data.

The second CTE ranks each row of the `Ago` data using [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) based on the ordering of the `TotalUnits`.  I have include the `Date` in the order so that if there are duplicate `TotalUnits` the first occurrence will be picked.

In the final query we are using `CASE` statements to pivot the data and aggregating the result for each `UCC12UPCCode` with `MAX` to create a single row for each `UCC12UPCCode`.

This query can be run over multiple `UCC12UPCCode`'s

Answer (score 1):

A similar solution as @MickyT:

```
select upc
     , max(case when asc_order = 1 then totalunits end) as min_units
     , max(case when desc_order = 1 then totalunits end) as max_units
     , max(case when asc_order = 1 then date end) as min_date
     , max(case when desc_order = 1 then date end) as max_date
from (
    SELECT row_number() over (order by TotalUnits) as asc_order
         , row_number() over (order by TotalUnits desc) as desc_order
         , upc
         , TotalUnits
         , Date
    FROM (
        SELECT  *   FROM    #RTG_Lookup2_4_Ago
        UNION
        SELECT  *   FROM    #RTG_Lookup2_3_Ago
        UNION
        SELECT  *       FROM    #RTG_Lookup2_2_Ago
        UNION
        SELECT  *       FROM    #RTG_Lookup2_Last1
    ) AS Ago
) as x
where 1 in (asc_order, desc_order)
group by upc;
```

Answer (score 1):

I took a different approach - thanks for the fiddle BTW. I think that you should consider changing your schema - you appear to be doing `UNION`s between a series of tables with different dates. This leads to a strange result

```
Low   High      Low date     High Date
 90    132    2018-04-14    2018-04-28
```

To me, it makes no sense to combine the low sale and date with the high sale and date - it makes much more sense in a relational theory to have this

```
Sale          Date        Volume
  90         2018-04-14      Low
 132         2018-04-28     High
```

To tackle this I did the following (see my own fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=7b94a509bd32e82977d4f0513143b8b7)):

```
CREATE TABLE movement (share_sale INTEGER, share_code VARCHAR(20), mvt_date DATETIME);

INSERT INTO movement VALUES (100, '01254601144', '2018-05-08');
INSERT INTO movement VALUES (150, '01254601144', '2018-05-08');
INSERT INTO movement VALUES (137, '01254601144', '2018-05-08');
INSERT INTO movement VALUES (112, '01254601144', '2018-05-08');
INSERT INTO movement VALUES (190, '01254601144', '2018-05-07');
INSERT INTO movement VALUES (260, '01254601144', '2018-05-07');
INSERT INTO movement VALUES (121, '01254601144', '2018-05-07');
INSERT INTO movement VALUES (165, '01254601144', '2018-05-07');
INSERT INTO movement VALUES ( 95, '01254601144', '2018-05-06');
INSERT INTO movement VALUES (239, '01254601144', '2018-05-06');
INSERT INTO movement VALUES (120, '01254601144', '2018-05-06');
INSERT INTO movement VALUES (111, '01254601144', '2018-05-06');
INSERT INTO movement VALUES (222, '01254601144', '2018-05-06');
INSERT INTO movement VALUES ( 86, '01254601144', '2018-05-06');
INSERT INTO movement VALUES ( 75, '01254601144', '2018-05-05');
INSERT INTO movement VALUES ( 45, '01254601144', '2018-05-05');
INSERT INTO movement VALUES ( 98, '01254601144', '2018-05-05');
INSERT INTO movement VALUES (120, '01254601144', '2018-05-05');
INSERT INTO movement VALUES ( 67, '01254601144', '2018-05-05');
```

And then I ran this query:

```
WITH cte1 AS
(
  SELECT MIN(share_sale) AS min_sale, mvt_date AS min_mvt_date
  FROM movement
  GROUP BY mvt_date
),
cte2 AS 
(
  SELECT MAX(share_sale) AS max_sale, mvt_date AS max_mvt_date
  FROM movement
  GROUP BY mvt_date
),
cte3 AS
(
SELECT * FROM cte1
JOIN
(
  SELECT * FROM cte2
) AS tab
ON cte1.min_mvt_date = tab.max_mvt_date
)
SELECT min_sale, max_sale, max_mvt_date AS mvt_date FROM cte3
```

Result:

```
min_sale  max_sale     date:
      45       120     05/05/2018 00:00:00
      86       239     06/05/2018 00:00:00
     121       260     07/05/2018 00:00:00
     100       150     08/05/2018 00:00:00
```

Now - on  a given day, I give you (with my simulated data) the lowest sale and the highest sale - to me, this makes more sense than putting two different dates in with 2 different figures. If there isn't a sale every day, then maybe something would have to be done with `NULL`s. Just a few thoughts.

Comment: If it helps, this is sales data. we cant "predict" which week will sell more/less. the 4 tables are weekly summaries of that weeks sales. In this situation, i need to know which of the 4 weeks sold the most/least and what that date is. The column `Volume` wouldnt help in this case (or atleast i dont think it would unless we update that column prior to running the query, correct me if im wrong)

Comment: Have a week_ending column so. The actual metric doesn't matter that much as long as you're comparing like with like on a weekly basis. But I don't see why you have tables for the last 4 weeks. Tables these days can easily hold hundreds of millions of records - I'd amalgamate if I were you  - unless you're Walmart :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `corelated subquery` to get your desired result

```
SELECT
    MIN(Ago.TotalUnits) AS LowMvmt,
    MAX(Ago.TotalUnits) AS HighMvmt,
    (select Date
     from #TempAgo as Ago2
     where min(Ago.totalunits) = ago2.totalunits) as lowdate,
    (select Date
     from #TempAgo as Ago2
     where max(Ago.totalunits) = ago2.totalunits) as highdate
FROM 
    #TempAgo as Ago
```